# Function is $1$ when rational and $-1$ when irrational

Tags: limits, functions

$$\begin{cases}h(x)=1&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\h(x)=-1&x\text{   irrational}
\end{cases}$$

> Find $\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}} h(x)$

It looks very simple because $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational , so $\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}} h(x)= -1$.

Is it true ?
Thanks.

Comment: "The limit does not exist!" -- Cady Heron

Comment: Not quite right. In fact, the limit does not exist. To see why it is true, I suggest thinking about this in terms of the definition of a limit.

Comment: Consider doing an epsilon-delta proof and show how there is no rational number really close to $\sqrt2$ and you'll see the error here.

Comment: Why do you think that $\lim_{x\to \sqrt{2}} h(x) = h(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: An alternative to a $\epsilon-\delta$ proof is by finding two different sequences converging to $\sqrt{2}$ which gives different limits thereby proving the limit does not exist. For example the limit along the sequence $x_n = \{1.4,1.41,1.414,1.4142,\ldots\}$ is $1$ since every $x_n$ is rational so $h(x_n) = 1$ for all $n$ and so is the limit. Now try finding a sequence $y_n\to \sqrt{2}$ where $h(y_n) = -1$ for all $n$ (Hint: rational + irrational = irrational).

Comment: Remember above all that the limit $x\to a$ has *nothing* to do with the value of the function at $a$.

Comment: @Winther What about $y_n = \left \{ \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{n} \right \}$ ?

Comment: That works perfectly!

Comment: @Winther Ok i got your point.
But, Why $x_n = \left \{ 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.414, 1.4142, ... \right \}$
Is a Sequence ?

Comment: $x_n$ is $\sqrt{2}$ to the first $n$ decimal places. It's just the simplest rational sequence I could think of that converges to $\sqrt{2}$. Another way to write $x_n$ is $x_n = \{ \frac{\lfloor \sqrt{2} 10^n\rfloor}{10^n}\}$.

Comment: @Winther Its not the notation.
I confused about the specific sequence.
There is no need for general term like mine in $y_n$ ?
Can i just pick up numbers and call them a sequence ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Winther Sorry i didnt see the first comment.
But, In genreal , There is no need for general term ?

Comment: Yes. That is perfectly fine. Note that we have no formula for the $n$'th prime, but we can guarantee that it exists and it's unique so it makes perfectly sense to talk about the $n$'th prime without an explicit formula for it. The same is the case here: we have defined $x_n$ as $\sqrt{2}$ up to $n$ decimal digits which is well-defined definition and you can in principle calculate $x_n$ if needed by computing $\sqrt{2}$ to enough precision and truncating at the $n$'th decimal place.

Answer (score 5):

The limit does not exist.

To see this, note that given any $\delta > 0$ there exists a rational number $x \in (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}+\delta)$ and an irrational number $y \in (\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}+\delta)$. For such values of $x$ and $y$, we have $h(x)-h(y) = 2$, and so taking $\varepsilon = 1$ in the (negation of the) definition of a limit shows that no limit exists.

Intuitively, the function takes both values $1$ and $-1$ arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{2}$, so it can't have a limit at $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not defined because the rationals and irrationals are dense in the real numbers.

thinking sequentially: you can approach $\sqrt{2}$ by either rationals or irrationals so the limit must be both -1 and 1, which is impossible.